# Selecting amino acid with the same length

Tags: r

I have a column of amino acid with different length like this

[image]

In R how I can select amino acid with the length of 14  (14 alphabets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `nchar` with `subset`, e.g.,

```
subset(v,nchar(v)==14)
```

Comment: Sorry how I can get the median of length of amino acids here?

Comment: @Mussa What do you mean `median of length of amino acids`?